# Problems searching directories

Tags: python, python-3.7

This function keeps throwing a name error. I thought it would throw an IO Error or something. Instead it tells me that the function is not defined, which to me, it clearly is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from os import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

This is in a class for the pyqt4 ui.

```
class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    Y = datetime.now().year

    def __init__(self):
        "Create UI"
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnSearch.clicked.connect(self.Search_File)
        self.btnCalculate.clicked.connect(self.Calculate)
        self.btnClear.clicked.connect(self.Clear)
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.Exit)

    def Search_File(self, x):
        cur_dir = os.getcwd()
            while True:
                file_list = os.listdir(cur_dir)
                parent_dir = os.path.dirname(cur_dir)
                File_Path_Search = x
                if File_Path_Search in file_list:
                    break
                if cur_dir == parent_dir:
                    break
                else:
                    cur_dir = parent_dir

    y = Search_File(self, txtFile_Path_Search.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob/Documents/Python Inquiry YES∕NO Program/Inquiry.py", line 68, in Calculate
    y = Search_File(self, txtFile_Path_Search.text())
NameError: name 'Search_File' is not defined
```

Comment: In what environment are you running this? I get the predictable (because very much more logically)  `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`  -- which you can manually verify to be true.

Comment: The code you have posted would raise an error because `self` is not defined and `txtFile_Path_Search` is not defined. Evidently this is not a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a number of errors in your code, unless this isn't your full code.
Is the full code or is just a snippet?
Cause what you are trying belongs in a class. If it does belong in a class, try:

```
self.Search_File(txtFile_Path_Search.text())
```

Provide full code if you haven't.

**Edit:**

Try using:

```
self.Search_File(txtFile_Path_Search.text())
```

Comment: This is a code snippet. It is in a class. I am using it with pyqt4.